# Closure and return values

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the code below? I'm confused about the role of
`return f();`

1. Does `return f();` call the method `f` and return the result? (i.e. the return of `f`)
2. Does `return f();` return an object?

If I change `return f();` to just `f();` then `checkscope = undefined`

```
var scope = "global scope";          // A global variable
function checkscope() {
    var scope = "local scope";       // A local variable
    function f() { return scope; }   // Return the value in scope here
    return f();
}
checkscope()                         // => "local scope"
```

Comment: 1) yes 2) no, it returns a string 3) if you remove the `return` then `checkscope` doesn't return anything, hence you will get `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: F returns exactly what it says it does. The point here is to show ES5 scoping, e.g., there's only function scope.

Comment: There's no closure here. The function `f` isn't returned, so the environment isn't stored after the `checkscope` function finishes.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, there is. `f` is a closure, even though it doesn't survive the call. That's why it has access to `scope` within `checkscope`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. `return` returns whatever the expression on the RHS resolves to
2. You can see what `f` returns: `return scope;`, and `scope` is assigned on the previous line. It is a string.

> If I change return f(); to just f(); checkscope = undefined

Well yes. If you don't have a `return` statement in a function, it returns `undefined`

Comment: ok thanks , Just to clarify  -  return f() calls the method f(); the method f returns to value of var scope (to the caller).  Finally the string 'global scope' is returned

Comment: @stckpete: Yup. But it's a function, not a method.

Answer (score 1):

It's #1. `return f()` *calls* `f` and then returns what `f` returns. The fact that `f` is a closure over the call to `checkscope` means that it has access to `scope` within that call's context, and so `f` reads the current value of `scope`, which is `"local scope"` (a string), and returns that value.

> Does `return f();` return an object?

No, a string (see above).

> If I change `return f();` to just `f();` then `checkscope = undefined`

That's because when you call a function that doesn't terminate with a `return <value>` statement, the result of calling it is the value `undefined`. By removing the `return`, you remove the return value of `checkscope`.

---

Here's a more interesting version:

```
function memo(value) {
    function f() { return "value is '" + value + "'"; }
    return f; // Note! No (), not calling it, returning the function
}
var f1 = memo("hi");
var f2 = memo("there");
f1(); // "value is 'hi'"
f2(); // "value is 'there'"
```

That takes it a step further, allowing `f` (the closure) to exist beyond the end of the call to `memo`, which keeps the context of that specific call to `memo` alive, which means we can use the `value` specific to that context.